# Storm like structure in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm

You know how in Apache Storm you can have a Spout streaming data to multiple Bolts. Is there a way to do something similar in Apache Spark?

I basically want that there be one program to read data from a Kafka Queue and output it to 2 different programs, which can then process it in their own, different ways.

Specifically, there would be a reader program that would read data from the Kafka queue and output it to 2 programs x and y. x would process the data to calculate metrics of one kind (in my case it would calculate the user activities) whereas y would calculate metrics of another kind (in my case this would be checking activities based on different devices).

Can someone help me understand how this is possible in Spark?

Comment: Interesting question! Would you care to elaborate about your "2 different programs" output?

Comment: So in general these could be any programs that need to read data from the same source. In my case, I want one program to be processing that data and calculating metrics whereas the other one should take that data and create a backup in s3.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the additional information please?

Comment: As for backing up in s3, that should be a regular save already available in Spark. And as the the other you might want to consider a connector to HBase or Elasticsearch.

Comment: One more thing, if you don't try to be more specific about what you need. Your question will be flagged as broad and thus won't be resolved and maybe deleted even thought it's interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit it right away. I understand my specific use case might be done in another way as well. But I will be adding a bunch of use cases to it in the future and hence wanted to know if it could be done the storm-way.

Comment: I have added the required details.

Comment: Why not using Storm?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax because I've been using Spark for data analytics and am used to it more now. Half my project is already built on Spark so want to continue it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply create two topologies?

1. Both topologies have a spout reading from the kafka topic (yes, you can have multiple topologies reading from the same topic; I have this running on production systems). **Make sure that you use different spout configs, otherwise kafka-zookeper will see both topologies as being the same**. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka).

> Spoutconfig is an extension of KafkaConfig that supports additional fields with ZooKeeper connection info and for controlling behavior specific to KafkaSpout. The Zkroot will be used as root to store your consumer's offset. The id should uniquely identify your spout.

```
public SpoutConfig(BrokerHosts hosts, String topic, String zkRoot, String id);
```

2. Implement program x in topology x and program y in topology y.

---

Another option would have two graphs of bolts subscribing from the same spout, but **IMHO this is not optimal, because failed tuples** (which are likely to fail only in one single graph) **would be replayed to both graphs, event if they fail in only one of the graphs**; and therefore some kafka messages will end being processed twice, using tow separated topologies you avoid this.

Comment: What you suggest is for working with Apache Spark? Or Storm?

Comment: @PraveshJain for Storm. But for Spark probably you should use the same approach; two distinct programs reading from the same same kafka topic and you need to make sure the kafka clients are seen by the zookeper as different clients (therefore careful with the copy past of the kafka client..).

Comment: I realised I could do that. Creating two separate programs can always be done. I wanted to know if this can be optimised by separating the common code in a different program.

Comment: @PraveshJain if you do your "optimization" you might end processing the kafka messages twice. I explained that in my last paragraph.

Comment: Processing them twice cannot be excluded in any case.